# ASP.NET GET request always returns blank

Tags: asp.net, json, object, response

I'm trying to make an endpoint to return a JSON response.  I've tried narrowing it down to just the object and all I receive is {} or [{}] as a response.  After debugging I confirmed that the object was being created correctly but when returning the response it was always blank.  Below is simplified code but still has the same issue.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
[Route("{application}")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get(string application)
{
    List<RequestedSetting> requestedSettings = new List<RequestedSetting>();
    RequestedSetting rs = new RequestedSetting("foo", "bar");
    requestedSettings.Add(rs);
    return Json(requestedSettings);
}

public class RequestedSetting
{

    public string Name;
    public string Value;

    public RequestedSetting(string name, string value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
[Route("{application}")]
[HttpGet]
public List<RequestedSetting> Get(string application)
{
    List<RequestedSetting> requestedSettings = new List<RequestedSetting>();
    RequestedSetting rs = new RequestedSetting("foo", "bar");
    requestedSettings.Add(rs);
    return requestedSettings;
}
```

[image]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsDRS.png]

Comment: It's not possible that this code would return nothing as it stands here. There must be something else you are not showing us. Have you stepped through the code while debugging? Are you sure this method is being called?

Comment: @DavidG I've added the screenshots of the test.

Comment: What does the `RequestedSetting` class look like? Do you have any custom model binders or serialisation code?

Comment: As @DavidG says you have to check the serialization of RequestedSetting class. The array is not empty because of {} that means wrong serialization of added object.

Comment: @DavidG, I've added the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields are not supported for serialisation in `System.Text.Json`. see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#include-fields) for more info.

Instead, change your class to use properties:

```
public class RequestedSetting
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public RequestedSetting(string name, string value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, i'm going to hide under a rock now.  Thanks.

Comment: It's easy to miss things like this when you're right in the middle of the code.